# Issue with Django startproject

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and python. I am currently trying to create a new django project by doing "django-admin startproject project" in the terminal, which works, but the only file that is in the folder is manage.py. I am not sure why the other files such as settings.py, urls.py, etc. are not located there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run

```
django-admin startproject my_project_name
```

Your project structure will look like this

```
my_project_name/
    manage.py
    my_project_name/
        settings.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
        urls.py
```

If you didn't get something like that then you probably didn't install Django correctly so try running

```
pip3 uninstall django
pip3 install django
```

Also if you are ono mac and didn't configure permissions properly and django-admin tells you command not found then run:

```
python3 -m django <The django-admin command you want>
```

One last note, you don't have to create a virtual environment to start working with Django, so didn't confuse yourself with them and focus on Django only

Comment: You are welcome :) don't forget to mark the correct answer as accepted from the ✅ sympol

Answer (score 2):

please try this one:

```
django-admin startproject project .
```

Please note the `.` at the end of the line.

After running it, you should have a `project` folder, and several files inside of that folder (**init**.py, asgi.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py)

*****EDIT*****
it is best to use separate environments for each django project.

1. make sure you downloaded and installed python.
2. in the terminal, first make directory for this project.

```
$ mkdir project2020
$ cd project2020
```

after this step: you should have something like
`MacBook-Air:project2020 user$`

3. set up virtual environment

```
$ python3 -m venv myvenv
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
```

after this step: you should have something like the :
`(myvenv) MacBook-Air:project2020 user$` # note (myvenv)

4. you can now install Django

```
$ python -m pip install Django
```

It will take some time to install

5. now it's time to create a new project

```
(myvenv) MacBook-Air:project2020 user$ django-admin startproject mysite .
```

Here, make sure you add `.` at the end.

6. check your `project2020` folder. you should see what I wrote before.

Comment: I get this error in terminal: CommandError: /Users/user/.DS_Store already exists. Overlaying a project into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files.

Comment: you might want to delete current folder, and remake directory and run the command.

Comment: yeah i tried that a few times but still no luck :/

Comment: Could you show your command line? The one with $?

Comment: MacBook-Air:~ user$ django-admin startproject project1

Comment: updated answer. you really want to have your django project in virtual environment.