# AttributeError: module 'tokenize' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, django, pip

```
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\Documents\django_app\obj\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.search_scope import SearchScope
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\models\search_scope.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import normalize_path, redact_password_from_url
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    __import__('pip._vendor.packaging.requirements')
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 5257, in <module>
    _escapedPunc = Word( _bslash, r"\[]-*.$+^?()~ ", exact=2 ).setParseAction(lambda s,l,t:t[0][1])
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1442, in setParseAction
    self.parseAction = list(map(_trim_arity, list(fns)))
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1211, in _trim_arity
    this_line = extract_stack(limit=2)[-1]
  File "c:\users\sidiy\documents\django_app\obj\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1195, in extract_stack
    frame_summary = traceback.extract_stack(limit=-offset+limit-1)[offset]
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 211, in extract_stack
    stack = StackSummary.extract(walk_stack(f), limit=limit)
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 366, in extract
    f.line
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 288, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\sidiy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\linecache.py", line 136, in updatecache
    with tokenize.open(fullname) as fp:
AttributeError: module 'tokenize' has no attribute 'open'
```

I'm trying to install Django on my computer and whenever I tried It shows the AttributeEroor above!
It's python3!
I need help with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi you should install django in a virtual environment. check my answer in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065535/issue-with-django-startproject/65065625#65065625

Comment: I still getting the same error!

Comment: maybe this can help you https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/348

Comment: I still get the same error I think there might a be multi-file with the same name "tokenize", but I still can't detect the error

Comment: are you familiar with the terminal command line. maybe you can detect where the "tokenize" files are.

Comment: Not really let me try it

Comment: I still can't detect it:(

Comment: hmm.. i ran out of idea... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about python but I will try to answer your question.
open up command prompt and type

```
py -m pip install django
```

it should install Django into your computer.
again I don't know much about python so my answer may not be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today.
In my case, I switched from **PyCharm** to **VScode** and ran into this problem.

I solved it by just **reinstalling python**. That's all, good luck :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).